# Unable to update mongolab data

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, mlab

I'm using angularjs, combined with mongolab, to create a basic application.

[Here is my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3oLkaerGUQSt86OyWDtl?p=preview)

The problem is, i tried to update the date (when i click on "editer"),but when i submit the form, got this **error** :

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'update'
```

The update method is defined, so i don't understant the error, any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your Project factory a little bit:

**updated after comment**

```
angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Project', function($resource) {
        var ProjectApi = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
                '/villes/collections/universities/:id',
                {apiKey: '7pcSaEmpVzZ90V6CVggeHa6Ys71uaZOA'}, {
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
        );

        var Project = function(data) {
            angular.extend(this, data);
        };

        Project.query = ProjectApi.query;
        Project.get = ProjectApi.get;

        Project.prototype.update = function(cb) {
          return ProjectApi.update({id: this._id.$oid},
                angular.extend(this, {_id: undefined}), cb);
        };
        Project.prototype.destroy = function(cb) {
          return ProjectApi.remove({id: this._id.$oid}, cb);
        };
        return Project;

    });
```

In `EditCtrl` you make a strange thing:

```
function EditCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams, Project) {
   var self = this;
   // Project is already defined in arguments and it is a service 
   var Project = Project.instance();
}
```

Calling `Project.instance()` will return you plain resource object that doesn't have any update() method! Look at your code in Project factory.

Also change code in EditCtrl:

```
function EditCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams, Project) {
        var self = this;
        Project.get({id: $routeParams.projetId}, function(projet) {
            self.original = projet;
            $scope.projet = new Project(self.original);
        });

        $scope.save = function() {
            $scope.projet.update(function() {
                $location.path('/list');
            });
        };
    }
```

And finally you will have it working.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOmMu81ApyfSHM1lniVz?p=preview)

Comment: This is how i builded my code at first before changing it. The problem with this code is, when i try to display the data of each record with `<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in projet"><div>{{key}}:{{val}}</div>    </div>` i have 2 extra lines : update and destroy (see in the "editer" view), but i just want to display the mongolab fields (id, name, rang)

Comment: I've updated `Project` factory in my answer. Of course, it's only a way to do so. I think this nice thread about prototype in javascript will be helpful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work .